# Is there a way to Ignore specific property in asp.net core Include function from many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on Asp.net core 5 Web-api, I am using many to many relationship between User entity and Permission entity, and I need to load users permission from the database using eager loading but the data is returning a looped information including users full information but I only load the permissions. I am using a Dto to return the Json data. Here is my models and my code

Permission Model

```
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClaimName { get; set; }
    public IList<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

UserPermission model

```
public class UserPermission
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

User model

```
public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime LastActive { get; set; }
    public IList<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

My user Dto

```
public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

My function

```
var sss = _context.UserPermissions
            .Include(l => l.Permission)
            .Where(v => v.UserId == user.Id)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: The query you have shown in the post will not include `AppUser` data in the query result. But I guess you are showing only a part of the code, and before this query you actually queried for `AppUser`. If that is the case, please edit your post and include any query you performed before the current one.

Comment: Actually it will return the user from UserPermission entity by lazy loading. but I already find my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[JsonIgnore]` on the properties that we want to exclude.
note that we should use "using Newtonsoft.Json" name space not using "System.Text.Json.Serialization"